# Where can I find the API documentation of beam_parse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I came across following two code snippets when I am reading through a code base:

1. `for beam in self.nlp_.entity.beam_parse([doc], beam_width=16, beam_density=0.0001)[0]:`
2. `for beam in self.nlp_.entity.beam_parse([doc], beam_width=16, beam_density=0.0001):`

I am not sure what's the difference between adding `[0]` at the end and without it. I tried to search for the API documentation for the method `beam_parse`, but I got nothing. And it seems to be implemented not in Python. I want to know the usage of this API.